# React Native single nested screen doesn't track the stack so goBack() doesn't work as expected

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have product categories which are multiple levels deep.

I've created a reusable `Categories Screen` which renders the first layer in a flatList. If I press on a category it navigates to the same `Categories Screen` and passes in the second layer and so on. Example:

**Add Product Screen > Category Screen (L1) > Category Screen (L2) > Category Screen (L3)**

The problem is when I press `navigation.goBack()` in (L3) it takes me back to `Product Screen`, which I guess is the 'root'.

**Instead, I'd really like `goBack` to take me to L2.**

I'm assuming it doesn't because I'm reusing the same screen, but I'm not sure how to nest a single screen and maintain the stack history without overwriting itself.

**Here is the navigator:**

```
  <Stack.Navigator ...>
    <Stack.Screen
      component={ProductScreen}
      name="ProductScreen"
    />
    <Stack.Screen
    component={CategoryScreen}
    name="CategoryScreen"
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

**Here is the Category Screen:**

```
export const CategoryScreen = ({ navigation }: ScreenProps) => {
  const renderItem: ListRenderItem<string> = ({item}) => {
      ...
      <Pressable onPress={() => handleCategoryPress()}>
      ...
      </Pressable>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ScreenContainer goBack={navigation.goBack}>
      <FlatList data={categories} renderItem={renderItem} />
    </ScreenContainer>
  );

  function handleCategoryPress() {
   ...
    navigation.navigate(
      'CategoryScreen',
      { categories: filteredCategories, level: nextLevel },
    );
  }
};
```

**Here are my versions:**

```
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this changing `navigation.navigate` to `navigate.push`:

```
  function handleCategoryPress() {
   ...
    navigation.push(  // <--- here
      'CategoryScreen',
      { categories: filteredCategories, level: nextLevel },
    );
  }
```